# My Network code is just working in my local network

Tags: c#, server, udp, client

I'm trying to program a UDP Server and Client. I tried out the code and everything worked fine, but when I tried to do the same, with my VPS as server and my computer as client, it didn't work. I opened all relevant ports on upd and tcp, but it still not work. Can anyone help me?

```
Server:
public partial class Network
    {
        private UdpClient Socket { get; set; }
        private IPEndPoint EpFrom = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        public void Bind(string address, int port)
        {
            this.Socket = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(address), port));
            Receive();
        }

        public void Send(string text)
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
            Socket.Send(data, data.Length);
        }

        private void Receive()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hearing on localhost 11111");
            byte[] data = Socket.Receive(ref EpFrom);
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
        }
    }


Call:
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Server.Start();
            Network server = new Network();
            server.Bind("127.0.0.1", 11111);
        }

Client:
public class Network
    {
        private UdpClient Socket { get; set; }
        private IPEndPoint EpFrom = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

        public void Server(string address, int port)
        {
            this.Socket = new UdpClient(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(address), port));
            Receive();
        }

        public void Client(string address, int port)
        {
            this.Socket = new UdpClient(port);
            this.Socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(address), port));
        }

        public void Send(string text)
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
            Socket.Send(data, data.Length);
            Socket.Close();
        }

        private void Receive()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hearing on localhost 11111");
            byte[] data = Socket.Receive(ref EpFrom);
            Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data));
        }
    }

Call:
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Network client = new Network();
            client.Client("ADDRESS", 11111);
            client.Send("test");
        }
```

It seems like the connection isn't go out from the client, because my vps don't show any activities between me and him.
But don't trust. If you have any questions, please ask.

Comment: Are you sure the code you submitted is the actual code? I see `server.Bind("127.0.0.1", 11111)` and `client.Client("ADDRESS", 11111)`: the first clearly state the server will listen only on local requests (no network allowed) and I hardly see how the second can work anyway (what does "ADDRESS" stand for?).

Comment: Many VPS providers block external traffic on all ports except select services like SSH or HTTP/HTTPS. Some even block those by default. You may need to explicitly allow connections on your specified port on the VPS.

Comment: "ADRESS" is just a placeholder because I don't want that everyone can see the IP.

Comment: To Patrick: This could be. Can you say me how to enable this port? I already enabled it in ufw.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code on my windows pc. Intern it worked fine, but extern, it didn't. It must not be a problem with my vps.